# partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I have a very simple kafka producer and consumer written in Python. For some reason, it doesn't work. It used to work and apparently something has changed in the environment, I can't figure out why. But I did figure out that I probably didn't write the programs well enough, and they worked up to now by chance.

So here goes:

Consumer program: `kafkasend.py`

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
from json import dumps
import base64

def create_producer():
    return KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=["iac-di-stg-us-kafka1:9092"],
                         value_serializer=lambda x: dumps(x).encode('utf-8'))

producer = create_producer()

ftp_full_path = "/usr/001D000001CJhyRIAT/MyUploads/01509235/data.zip"
datafeeder_base_path = "/var/temp/data"

body = {
    'ftppath': base64.b64encode(ftp_full_path),
    'dfpath': datafeeder_base_path + '.txt'
}

print("sending kafka message to what: " + str(body))
producer.send('what', value=body)
producer.flush()
producer.close()
```

Consumer program: `kafkareceive.py`

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
from json import loads
from time import sleep
import sys
import base64

consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    'what',
    bootstrap_servers=['iac-di-stg-us-kafka1:9092'],
    enable_auto_commit=True,
    auto_commit_interval_ms=1000,
    group_id='my-group',
    max_poll_records=1,
    max_poll_interval_ms=10000,
    value_deserializer=lambda x: loads(x.decode('utf-8')))
print("Created consumer")

for message in consumer:
    print("Topic: " + message.topic)
    if message.topic == "what":
        print("ftppath: " + base64.b64decode(message.value['ftppath']))
        print("dfpath: " + message.value['dfpath'])
        commandString = ("/var/analysis/run_analysis.sh \""
                         + message.value['dfpath'] + "\" \"" + message.value['ftppath'] + "\" &")
        print(commandString)
```

When I run the programs, kafkasend displays this:

```
sending kafka message to what: {'ftppath': 'L3Vzci8wMDFEMDAwMDAxQ0poeVJJQVQvTXlVcGxvYWRzLzAxNTA5MjM1L2RhdGEuemlw', 'dfpath': '/var/temp/data.txt'}
```

It looks as if it's working, it doesn't throw anything, but I am not sure, it does take a while for the `flush()` to work. When I try to run console consumer, I don't get any messages:
`./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server iac-di-stg-us-kafka1:9092 --topic what` returns lines of the form:

```
[2022-03-09 07:01:24,505] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-39546-1, groupId=console-consumer-39546] 1 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including [what-0] (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

When I try to run a console producer, I get the same warning:

```
[2022-03-09 07:08:19,182] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] 1 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including [what-0] (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

And of course, when I run the `kafkareceive.py` program, it creates a consumer and then gets stuck.

Can anyone tell me where the problem is? Where should I look? Is it actually some misconfiguration of the kafka node (or nodes)? Is something missing in my programs?

--- Addendums---

Kafka server.properties:

```
broker.id=-1
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=zookeeper:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
```

The output of the command `./kafka-topics.sh --describe --topic what --bootstrap-server localhost:9092`

```
Topic: what     PartitionCount: 1       ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs: segment.bytes=1073741824
        Topic: what     Partition: 0    Leader: none    Replicas: 1005  Isr: 1005
```

Comment: Can you please show your kafka server properties?

Comment: And the output from `kafka-topics --describe --topic what`

Comment: @OneCricketeer: Thank you. Added the requested (in the body of the question).

Comment: You only have one broker, then? You probably will want to manually set `broker.id=1005` and restart it since this is the value that is listed by the topic. By default, I think it should start at `1001`, or are you running the command from `iac-di-stg-us-kafka1` machine?